# I can not access a form on submit

Tags: javascript, forms

I can’t access a form via JavaScript. The Javascript code in the header, between the `<head>` tags.

An error message tells me that the form does not exist. So I used the onload evenement but it does not solve the problem.

```
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {

document.getElementsByName('form_login').onsubmit = function(){ }

} ;

window.onload = function() {

document.getElementsByName('form_login')[0].onsubmit = function(){ }

} ;
</script>
</head>


<body>
<form action="/login" method="post" name="form_login">
<input type="text" tabindex="1" name="username" id="username" size="25" maxlength="40" value="" />
<input type="password" tabindex="2" id="password" name="password" size="25" maxlength="25" />
<input type="checkbox" name="autologin" id="autologin" tabindex="4" checked="checked" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="query" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="login" tabindex="6" value="Connexion" />
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `onsubmit="login(this)"` to the `form` element and have this function (`login`) defined in your javascript code loaded on that page.

```js
function login(form) {
  // ... some code here
};

// ... OR ...

loginForm.onsubmit = function() {
  // ... some code here
  // ... return false is required to prevent form submitting
  return false;
};
```

```html
<form id="loginForm" onsubmit="login(this); return false">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ugh, why inline css? If it was reasonable to downvote for using inline css i honestly would, i just can't see why people can use that piece of horror `:P`

Comment: @Tarekis That'd be called `inline JavaScript`, though! It results in the same, but I'd prefer keep it a bit hidden inside the script.

Comment: Wo-a-hoops! I somehow mixed `css` and `js` .. `(ง>ᗝ<)ง`, let's just lay off SO for today then i guess, ha!

Answer (score 1):

There's no error. See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wceb0mr2/2/).

Put your script inside a `<script>` tag like this:

```
<head>
<script>
    //The script
</script>
</head>
```

Then, inside of `<script>` & `</script>`:

```
onload=function(){ 
    document.getElementsByName('form_login')[0].onsubmit=function(e){
        e.preventDefault();//avoid page refreshing to see the following alert
        alert("Yeah! I see, it works.")//indicate that it works
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the <script> tags.

Comment: @Flamin_ Sorry! There's no error, or try to remove the first definition of the property `onload`.

Comment: @Flamin_ glad_of_help

Comment: not safe if some other form with the same name will be inserted before this one

Comment: @Oleg Meleshko Yeah, but it's not answering how to make it "safe", and yeah solving the problem of the guy.